# On Facebook, is there a way to stop notifications for other people writing on the wall of an event I have RSVPed to?

Tags: facebook, notifications

It drives me crazy that I get notifications from people I don't know who have written on the wall of an event that I (along with 3000 other people) was invited to.

I see that you can prevent getting emailed whenever this happens, but is there way to avoid the notification (i.e. the red "globe" with the number lighting up) entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! For Facebook's Notifications on a specific event, here's how to turn them off.

1. Go to the event page.
2. Click the "Gear" icon in the upper right.
3. "Turn off Notifications"

Also related, to disable Email Notifications for events (every event, not just a specific one)

1. Go to your "Account Settings"
2. "Notifications" from the left
3. Under "Events" uncheck "Posts on the wall of an event you've joined"

Comment: Thanks - I think the first method (per-event) will work, but I'm pretty sure the second method (for all events) only controls whether you get an email or not, though I could be wrong.  I already had that unchecked but still get the "within facebook/red globe" notifications.  We'll see if the per-event method works though...

Comment: Ah, I do believe you're right, that the second part is for email only. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: That doesn't work anymore. There isn't a gear icon on the event.

Comment: Marianna, the gear is still visible on every FB event I've joined, and the option for "Turn off Notifications" is also there.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, to get the gear, one must first select *Going*.

Unfortunately, even after selecting *Stop notifications* within the event, they still keep coming.

Also, regarding the original suggestion: There simply is no *Events* option in the FB general Notifications controls, only a *Group* option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no gear icon if you Declined the invitation. There is an issue with FB. You have to say that you are Going to see the gear icon and turn off notifications. I'm sure Facebook is getting complaints about this and will fix it soon. It JUST started happening to me recently and it is insanely annoying.